# JSF-Request Scope -> How can i archieve an up-to-date list, and a reliable mapping from the table to the objects?

Tags: jsf, scope

hi i'm playing around with jsf 2.1

i have the following handler

```
@Controller("testHandler")
@Scope("request")
public class TestHandler {

    public class EntityObject {

        public EntityObject(String value) {
            this.value = value;
        }

        private String value = "";

        public String getValue() {
            return value;
        }

        public void setValue(String value) {
            log.info(this + " Set value from " + this.value + " to " + value);
            this.value = value;
        }
    }

    private Logger log = Logger.getLogger(getClass());

    private List<EntityObject> objects = new ArrayList<TestHandler.EntityObject>();

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        log.info("INIT");
        // addItem("O0");
        addItem("O1");
        addItem("O2");
        addItem("O3");
    }

    private void addItem(String name) {
        EntityObject e = new EntityObject(name);
        log.info("add " + e + " with value " + name);
        objects.add(e);
    }

    public List<EntityObject> getObjects() {
        return objects;
    }

    public void setObjects(List<EntityObject> objects) {
        this.objects = objects;
    }

}
```

and this jsf

```
    <h:form>
        <h:dataTable value="#{testHandler.objects}" var="object">

            <h:column>
                <h:inputText value="#{object.value}" />
            </h:column>

        </h:dataTable>

        <h:commandButton value="submit" />
    </h:form>
```

i'm running tomcat in debug mode so i can hot replace code.

now i'm opening the page

```
init | INIT
addItem | add TestHandler$EntityObject@41c3cce3 with value O1
addItem | add TestHandler$EntityObject@1dc06cd0 with value O2
addItem | add TestHandler$EntityObject@4427daf2 with value O3
```

- i see the table with 3 inputfields
- i add "change" to the end of each value
- i uncomment the "addItem("O0");" in the init method
- i hit submit button

->

```
init | INIT
addItem | add TestHandler$EntityObject@5d653eaa with value O0
addItem | add TestHandler$EntityObject@21f53acd with value O1
addItem | add TestHandler$EntityObject@6ae77a25 with value O2
addItem | add TestHandler$EntityObject@30449f8 with value O3
setValue | TestHandler$EntityObject@5d653eaa Set value from O0 to O1change
setValue | TestHandler$EntityObject@21f53acd Set value from O1 to O2change
setValue | TestHandler$EntityObject@6ae77a25 Set value from O2 to O3change
```

in the log it seems that the values aren't assigned to the objects referenced before, it seems that jsf just memorys the index of the list and updates the wrong objects.

What is the best scope for updating objects? How can i archieve an up-to-date list, and a reliable mapping from the table to the objects?

adding equals and hashcode functions didn't help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are mis-using the Request scope. It is not appropriate for updatable data. 
Beans in request scope are created for every request (button push or even AJAX call).

When you hit submit button, JSF will create new request and your request scope bean will be destoryed. But because you are staying on the same page, the JSF DataTable bean is not destoryed and it will go through all components and update the values.

Note that at this point JSF Table bean has three InputText components, it will update them: ie. only the first three items in list. JSF doesnt keep the full data in components, (waste of memory), just references.. So here's funny thing: if you create two items in second Init() JSF will give you an error.

Here is an excellent explanation of scopes with guidelines:
http://balusc.blogspot.ca/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html#ManagedBeanScopes

see also:
[How to choose the right bean scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031885/how-to-choose-the-right-bean-scope)

Answer (score 0):

In fact, JSF is not updating the wrong objects. Quoting the famous article [Communication in JSF 2.0](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html)

> @RequestScoped: a bean in this scope lives as long as the HTTP
>   request-response lives. It get created upon a HTTP request and get
>   destroyed when the HTTP response associated with the HTTP request is
>   finished (this also applies to ajax requests!).

So your bean is destroyed and created when you hit the "hit" button; during init it initializes your EntityObject array, so you cannot save the state.

You may read the link for different types of scope and choose tye one that suits best for your interests. If you do not have a specific case [ViewScoped](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/bean/ViewScoped.html) may help you.